# Alternative of trunc function in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using `trunc` function in postgresql like `trunc(date)` , but error is there "Function trunc(date) does not exist in postgresql". Please tell me the alternative function of `trunc` in postgresql

Comment: `trunc()` is used for truncating _numbers_, not dates.  Please describe what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the `date_trunc()` function, which is used to truncate timestamps.  The `trunc()` function is used for truncating numbers, not dates.

If you had a date and you wanted to truncate it to the hour, you could use:

```
date_trunc('hour', date)
```

If you wanted to truncate to the day, you could use this:

```
date_trunc('day', date)
```

[**Documentation**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

Answer (score 1):

if you only want cut to hour you can cast timestamp variable to date
example

```
timestamp_variable::date
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to help people with similar questions.

The function trunc() needs a numeric or a double precision entry:

```
trunc ( numeric ) → numeric

trunc ( double precision ) → double precision
```

Or if you need to set the decimals cases, it must be a numeric:

```
trunc ( v numeric, s integer ) → numeric
```

Comment: This is not what OP is asking.